# Deploying a War file to Azure

Tags: java, azure, tomcat

I am attempting to upload a War file of a web service to Azure, running tomcat 8.
I have the war file in the relevant webapps folder on onedrive, however the deployment consistently fails, and frustratingly it does so without an error message.

I'm pretty sure that if I can't use a method involving uploading the binary file to Azure, I cannot use Azure. When using repositories like github, the build would fail due to reference issues, so I believe that is not an option.

Unfortunately I **must** use Azure, I'm aware that with other services like AWS I'd be done in 5 minutes as you can directly upload without any Microsoft (tm) hassle.

Comment: Have you tried to upload a small and simple WAR?

Comment: I'm unaware of how to do that. Unless I'm mistaken, there is no direct upload option, because that's how Microsoft rolls, and so you need to upload your War file to somewhere like dropbox or onedrive, and have Azure grab it from there. The program is currently just a hello world service, so it's definitely not a case of size.

Comment: Why not use ftp (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploadingdownloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs/)

Comment: Have you tried to upload it via the manager app?
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Answer (score 8):

Normally, there are 4 ways to deploy a war file on Azure Web Apps: FTP, repository like Github/BitBucket or OneDrive/Dropbox, Kudu Tool, Azure Toolkit for Eclipse/IntelliJ.

First of all, you need to know [File structure on azure](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure). The Java war file must be deployed at the directory `webapps` under the `wwwroot` path of Azure Web Apps. You can access the Kudu tool url `https://<your-webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` to lookup it.

1. Using FTP for deployment, you can refer to the Kudu wiki page [`Accessing files via ftp`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-files-via-ftp) to know it, and set the FTP user & password via Azure portal as below.

[image]

2. Using repository like GitHub, you can refer to the Kudu wiki page [`Deploying from GitHub`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-GitHub) to know it. Please first make sure the file structure on GitHub repository as the same as its under your `wwwroot` directory, as below.

[image]
[image]

3. A convenient and fast way is using Kudu tool to drag & drop your war file into the `webapps` directory, as below.

[image]

4. If you had installed Azure Toolkit for Eclipse/IntelliJ, you can refer to [Deploy Java Web Apps to Azure using Eclipse](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deploy-java-web-apps-to-azure-using-eclipse/) or [IntelliJ: Deploy Java Web Apps to Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/intellij-deploy-java-web-apps-to-azure/) to do it.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: what if the .war file is not automatically extracting

Comment: If I use the option 3. To use Kudu.  From where the war file need to be drag from. I am able to get to Kudu but it is on the web and my war file is in my local computer?

Answer (score 4):

Quick note that gave me a lot of frustration to figure out. If you use ftp via a client (I use FileZilla for it), think about this:

Place the .war file under: site > wwwroot > webapps > [Place .war file here].

Do also change the .war file name to: ROOT.war

It has to be that name for the system to deploy it. At least for me, the GitHub integration is not working, so I use this ftp method.

The deployment via ftp can take several minutes to be deployed and running.