# How to deploy a war on azure web app using FTP

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy war file on azure web app service using FTP. But i dont see webapps folder under site/wwwroot as mentioned in many tutorials. I have selected web server as tomcat.I saw tutorials on old portal.when i create it from new portal,i dont see webapps folder

Comment: Just to confirm if you are following this official Quickstart which shows how to use the Azure CLI with the Azure Web App Plugin for Maven to deploy a .jar file, or .war file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java?pivots=platform-windows&tabs=tomcat

Comment: @SnehaAgrawal-MSFT yes i tried this way also...but my app is not getting deployed...and its showing only default web page hostingstart.html..even if i delete it

Comment: If you create the webapps folder in that directory and deploy the WAR there does that succeed?

Comment: @Peter Pan's answer will useful to you in the post which title is [Deploying a War file to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000170/deploying-a-war-file-to-azure).

Comment: @Jason Pan i managed to deploy jar file...and for different War files behaviour is different...but at least some war files are getting deployed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Azure App services, the recommended way to deploy a war package is using curl or Azure PowerShell. Details see: [deploy-war-file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-war-file)

I also tested on my side that deploying war file on Azure App service by PowerShell Command, it works perfectly for me:
[image]

My application page:

[image]

For how to get started with Azure PowerShell, please see: [get started with Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azps-4.8.0)